# Improving performance of python multithreading for downloading webpages

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2

I am trying to write python code that downloads web pages using separate threads.  Here is an example of my code:

```
import urllib2
from threading import Thread
import time

URLs = ['http://www.yahoo.com/',
        'http://www.time.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://www.slashdot.org/'
       ]


def thread_func(arg):
    t = time.time()
    page = urllib2.urlopen(arg)
    page = page.read()
    print time.time() - t




for url in URLs:
    t = Thread(target = thread_func, args = (url, ))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

I run the code and the threads seem to execute serially, if I'm not mistaken, with the time of the download measured but each one is output to console after a certain amount of time.  Am I coding this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `t.join()` blocks the current thread until the target thread ends. You're calling that right after you create the thread, so you don't have more than one downloader thread running at a time.

Change your code to this:

```
threads = []
for url in URLs:
    t = Thread(target = thread_func, args = (url, ))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# All threads started, now wait for them to finish
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: thanks.  just out of curiosity, i'm  getting output like this: 3.60282206535
4.05780601501
5.74620199203
9.5616710186...it looks like each time is taking longer instead of them being around the same time.  is this correct behavior?
...

Comment: The threads will start at roughly the same time, but will compete for your network bandwidth. A few threads will immediately start making requests, while the others block until the network is available.